# How do I merge a property of duplicated objects inside of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects that has duplicate resource_names

```
[ 
  {'resource_name': 'Objectname1', 'weekdays': [null, null, null, "vacation", "vacation"]},
  {'resource_name': 'Objectname2', 'weekdays': [null, null, "vacation", "vacation", "vacation"]},
  {'resource_name': 'Objectname1', 'weekdays': ["vacation", "vacation", null, null, null]},
  {'resource_name': 'Objectname1', 'weekdays': [null, null, "vacation", null, null]}  
]
```

My goal is that it would look like this:

```
[ 
  {'resource_name': 'Objectname1', 'weekdays': ["vacation", "vacation", "vacation", "vacation", "vacation"]},
  {'resource_name': 'Objectname2', 'weekdays': [null, null, "vacation", "vacation", "vacation"]}
]
```

It has merged the duplicated objects by resource_name and merged the weekdays without changing the length and keeping their position inside the array. When merging it should take the weekday that is not null. No object can have overlapping weekdays so that is not a problem.

How would I manage this? I tried going through my array of objects but what I did was looping through each element in the array and see if they had a duplicate. This only works when the element is duplicated once but not when there are 3 or more objects with the same resource_name.

Comment: what happens if they have the same name and both arrays are not null at the same index? and if the populated values do not match?

Comment: @JoshAdams this gets checked before and can't ever happen. I'm trying to expand an old code that uses an API which already checks that.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Right now you are asking strangers to do 100% of the work.

Comment: @ChrisBarr I was trying with different for loops through the array to check if the array has duplicated objects. (https://jsfiddle.net/e7fxzLr0/2/) The problem is I don't know how to merge the objects correctly and add them back to the initial array without disrupting the indexes and checking for more duplicates in the same array since it can have 3 different objects with the same resource_name. Now I'm busy trying to understand what the code in those 2 answers I got actually mean because that syntax is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const resource = [
  { 'resource_name': 'Objectname1', 'weekdays': [null, null, null, "vacation", "vacation"] },
  { 'resource_name': 'Objectname2', 'weekdays': [null, null, "vacation", "vacation", "vacation"] },
  { 'resource_name': 'Objectname1', 'weekdays': ["vacation", "vacation", null, null, null] },
  { 'resource_name': 'Objectname1', 'weekdays': [null, null, "vacation", null, null] }
];
  
const resObj = {};
  
resource.forEach((el)=>{
  
  if(resObj[el.resource_name]){
    
    el.weekdays.forEach((day,index)=>{
      if(day){
        resObj[el.resource_name].weekdays[index]=day;
      }
    });   
    
  }else{
    resObj[el.resource_name] = el;
  }
  
})
  
console.log(Object.keys(resObj).map(el=>resObj[el]))
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You could find the objects and map onlöy truty values.

```js
var data = [{ resource_name: 'Objectname1', weekdays: [null, null, null, "vacation", "vacation"] }, { resource_name: 'Objectname2', weekdays: [null, null, "vacation", "vacation", "vacation"] }, { resource_name: 'Objectname1', weekdays: ["vacation", "vacation", null, null, null] }, { resource_name: 'Objectname1', weekdays: [null, null, "vacation", null, null] }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { resource_name, weekdays }) => {
        var temp = r.find((o) => resource_name === o.resource_name);
        if (!temp) {
            r.push(temp = { resource_name, weekdays: [] });
        }
        temp.weekdays = weekdays.map((v, i) => temp.weekdays[i] || v);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```